# Integrate Bugsnag

Tags: plugin-development, error-handling

What would be a good approach to integrate a service like [Bugsnag](http://bugsnag.com)? Is there some kind of global Error/Exception Handler where everything is routed through and I could hook in?

**Edit:** Find the finished Plugin here: [craft-bugsnag](https://github.com/Goldinteractive/craft-bugsnag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yii does have [onError](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#onError-detail) and [onException](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#onException-detail) events that get raised when PHP errors/warnings/notices and exceptions happen.

You'd need to write a plugin that listened to those and did the Bugsnag magic, then.

Comment: nice, didn't know about those! Thanks.